# SendGrid API v3 PHP Library get verified_senders does not work?

Tags: php, api, sendgrid, http-status-code-403, sendgrid-api-v3

I successfully used SendGrid PHP Library installed by Composer to send emails.
So PHP API v3 Send works with my API Key and simple send process.
Then I decided to verify Senders to prevent failed send API requests.

So I followed instructions by documentation to get list of verified Senders:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/sender-verification/get-all-verified-senders

When trying to get verified senders I always receive statusCode 403 "access forbidden"

```
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(self::getApiKey());
    $response = $sendgrid->client->verified_senders()->get();
```

Support asked me to use already used PHP Library or Curl request.
So I tried Composer PHP SendGrid V3 Library, curl requests by PHP, Postman, always with 403 "access forbidden" response.
Some images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNl79.jpg

Any idea ? Thank you very much for each hint or working example in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

SendGrid API keys can be restricted to just certain APIs. My guess is that you created an API key that had the permissions to send emails, but maybe not other permissions.

I recommend you check the permissions for your API key and either edit them to add further permissions or create a new key that covers all the APIs you want to use right now.